# Using a 24" Apple Cinema Display with a Dell latitude E5470

Tags: windows-7, external-display, dell-latitude

Has anybody managed to use an Apple 24" Cinema Display with a laptop using the VGA port?  Mine is a Dell E5470 running Windows 7.

I have the latest drivers for the Intel graphic card installed. Cables and connections seem OK as it detects an unspecified monitor when everything is plugged in. However, the Cinema Display remains black.

I looked at downloading the Boot Camp drivers but I couldn’t find anything specific.

Comment: What is the resolution of the display? Does it have a VGA input or are you using some kind of adaptor?

Comment: @Mokubai resolution 1920x1080 currently using a VGA cable, a vga to minidislplay adapter and a female to female minidisplay port connector

Comment: Those adaptors probably will not work. There are almost no adaptors that will convert *from* VGA (presumably your laptop) to output *to* a DisplayPort monitor. Chaining random adaptors together will never work especially when the signals need active electronics to convert the signals. VGA is an analogue signal and requires work to convert to a digital DisplayPort signal. You need a DisplayPort output on your laptop to drive a DisplayPort monitor.